# How can i delimit string[] values

Tags: c#, asp.net, delimiter

How can i delimit and store string[] values? 
I have selected items more than once from the checkbox. After checked I get parent and child code and want to separate two of them.

Check box items stored in string[] `selectedItems`

[image]

Need to store another variable like this:

```
child[0]=120000
parent[0]=100000
child[1]=352000
parent[1]=100000
```

Comment: What is the outcome you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var temp = seledItems.Select(item => 
             {
                 string[] parts = item.Split('-');
                 return new { Child = int.Parse(parts[0], Parent = int.Parse(parts[1])};
             });
int[] child = temp.Select(x => x.Child).ToArray();
int[] parent = temp.Select(x => x.Parent).ToArray();
```

This at first creates a sequence of objects containing the `Child` and `Parent` values from your selected items.
Then it transforms this into the two arrays `child` and `parent` you required in your question.

---

An alternative could look like this:

```
int[] child = new int[seledItems.Length];
int[] parent = new int[seledItems.Length];
for(int i = 0; i<seledItems.Length; i++)
{
     string[] parts = seledItems[i].Split('-');
     child[i] = int.Parse(parts[0]);
     parent[i] = int.Parse(parts[1]);
}
```